# Quando coloco uma tela principal, esta tela principal desativa a calculadora na segunda tela

Tags: android

Fiz o App para somar dois numeros, porem quando coloco uma tela inicial apenas com um botao para chamar a tela de soma, os calculos da tela de soma ficam inativos, como resolver?Obrigado

**Tela MainActivity.java**

```
package br.com.frutasalmeidasantos.www.testefinal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void chamasolucao (View v) { setContentView(R.layout.activity_solucao); }
}
```

**Solucao.java**

```
package br.com.frutasalmeidasantos.www.testefinal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Solucao extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText campo1;
    EditText campo2;
    Button btcalc;
    TextView resposta;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_solucao);

        campo1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo1);
        campo2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo2);
        btcalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btcalc);
        resposta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resposta);

        btcalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String scampo1 = campo1.getText().toString();
                String scampo2 = campo2.getText().toString();

                if (scampo1.isEmpty() || scampo2.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Solucao.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                int ncampo1 = Integer.parseInt(scampo1);
                int ncampo2 = Integer.parseInt(scampo2);

                int nresposta = ncampo1 + ncampo2;

                resposta.setText(""+ncampo1+ "+" +ncampo2+ "=" +nresposta);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.frutasalmeidasantos.www.testefinal">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Solucao"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Altere o  método `chamasolucao()` para `public void chamasolucao (View v) { startActivity(new Intent(this, Solucao.class)); }`

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral, funcionou!

Answer (score -1):

Para solucionar o seu problema faça o seguinte:

Na linha `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {` adicione `implements View.OnClickListener` deixando a linha dessa forma:

`public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{`

Abaixo do `onCreate` você cria o método `public void onClick(View v){}`

O resultado será esse (**MainActivity**):

```
package br.com.frutasalmeidasantos.www.testefinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnSolucao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        btnSolucao=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSolucao);
        btnSolucao.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(this, Solucao.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

Comment: Fiz exatamente como sugeriu, ainda nao funcionou! Alguma sugestao?

Comment: @GilbertoAlmeida vc nn cria um novo metodo, você coloco o implements na sua public class antes do onCreate

Comment: Boa noite! vc pode me enviar o exemplo como no modelo acima? Sou iniciante e apesar de ter chegado ate aqui, agora travei! consigo executar a splash screen e a calculadora separada por exemplo, mas nao consigo fazer a calculadora funcionar quando tenho duas activities, ela fica com o botal calcular nulo.

Comment: Favor não utilizar snippet se não for um código executável no site, como em javascript, css e html.

Comment: @diegofm ??? nn entendi